# collecting set of files using tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am looking to generate a tcl script, which reads each line of a file, say `abc.txt`; each line of `abc.txt` is a specific location of set of files which need to be picked except the ones commented.
For example `abc.txt`  has

```
./pvr.vhd
./pvr1.vhd
// ./pvr2.vhd
```

So I need to read each line of `abc.txt` and pick the file from the location it has mentioned and store it in a separate file except the once which starts with "`//`"

Any hint  or script will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of doing this is to put a filter at the start of the loop that processes each line that causes the commented lines to be skipped. You can use `string match` to do the actual detecting of whether a line is to be filtered.

```
set f [open "abc.txt"]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach line $lines {
    if {[string match "//*" $line]} {
        continue
    }
    # ... do your existing processing here ...
}
```

This also works just as well when used with a streaming loop (`while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {…}`).